# Unable to bind value from java bean to jsp using jstl

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jstl, runtime-error

I have a String getter and setter that i am setting in my bean.

I am trying to get the value in my jsp using jstl like this :

```
    <jsp:useBean class="com.test.MyBean" id="results" scope="request"/>


    <script type="text/javascript">
    function setMyFields(){
    var flag="<c:out value='${results.sdateFlag}'/>";
    alert(flag);                
    var text_box = document.getElementById('mySelectedDate');
    if(flag=="true"){
    text_box.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
    }
    window.onload = setMyFields;
    </script>
```

I have imported jstl core as well in my jsp.

But when i do this i get an error like this :

```
    javax.servlet.ServletException: Unable to find a value for "sdateFlag" in object of class "com.test.MyBean" using operator "."
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:660)
    at com.ibm._jsp._pageMyAmount._jspService(_pageMyAmount.java:306)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:87)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:856)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1101)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:569)
    at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:478)
    at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.servlet.GenericServletWrapper.handleRequest(GenericServletWrapper.java:122)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:226)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppRequestDispatcher.forward(WebAppRequestDispatcher.java:321)
```

But ihave been debugging the java class using the java debugger and it seems the value is getting set. Then why is it not getting the value ?

**EDIT :** These are the setter and getter of my bean :

```
public void setDateFlag(String  b)          { sDateFlag = b; }
public String isDateFlag()                  { return sDateFlag; }
```

What's wrong here ? Am i missing something ?

Comment: Please add the code of your `MyBean` class

Comment: Why don't you use a simple EL instead of useBean ?

Comment: @NilsH : Okay i am gonna add the My Bean code.

Comment: @NoobUnChained : How do i use EL here ? Give some sample pointers , plz .

Comment: Post the bean code , I wanted you to use EL because it is supposed to be a better practice than useBean !!!

Comment: @NoobUnChained : I posted the bean code . Any ways , use bean is how the code base has  been configured here. Hence every jsp uses this to retrieve the setters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So , i got the problem fixed and it was a bizarre solution. The problem it seems is, any variable declared must follow java standards.  And my problem was , i had given the variable name as `sDateFlag` in my original proprietary code, which does not follow  the java naming conventions. When i removed it and gave it as `flag` , it started working. I R&D ed the answer  using this link here : [JSTL](http://www.devrecipes.com/2009/09/30/jstl-errorunable-to-find-a-value-for-property-in-object-of-class-using-operator/) . Though it's not fully correct, it led me to the root cause of my problem. And i will like to convey my thanks to all of you guys , who have replied to me, to make the process easy .

Answer (score 1):

You're treating the `dateFlag` as a boolean property, but it is in fact a `String`. So you "getter" should be called `getDateFlag`, not `isDateFlag`. As mentioned, the `isPropertyName` syntax is only applicable to properties of type `boolean`.

Also, `<c:out value='${results.dateFlag}'/>` isn't really needed. You should be able to simply do `${results.dateFlag}`.

Comment: Ok let me try this one. I will get back to you .

Comment: No, it does not work, I am getting the same error . Don't see how a method name can be such a pain .Its gotta be something else .

Comment: That's just how the JavaBean naming convention is. If you still get the error, something probably haven't been recompiled and/or re-reployed.

Comment: So, i have complied and recompiled several times. Still it did not work, got rid of c:out and still no luck. At last i did this :

 <%pageContext.setAttribute("dateFlag",results.getDateFlag());
 %>
 var flag='<c:out value="${dateFlag}"/>';

But the problem, it still follows the scriplet coding, which might cause XSS problems.

Comment: Whatever @NilsH mentioned should do the job for you, if it doesn't then you need to post the entire bean code for us !!!

Comment: *You should be able to simply do `${results.dateFlag}`* you're wrong here, it is right using `<c:out>` in this case. Still, since using `${}` notation, EL will use getters only. In order to use the setters as wel you should use deferred evaluation by the usage of `#{}` that is heavily used on JSF and Facelets. To the real problem: looks like `com.test.MyBean` class doesn't have a `dateFlag` field/property well declared, thus giving the problem. If it has, looks like OP isn't running the code he/she sees on the editor/IDE.

Comment: It should be entirely possible to use it without `c:out`, @LuiggiMendoza. Although maybe not the best suggestion if it is raw, user entered data, which should not be printed unescaped. There's no setters involved in the JSP in the example, so `#{}` wouldn't make a difference.